# How to combine 2 observables and emit values based on specific conditions in Angular 8

Tags: angular, observable

I have `2 observables` that I want to `combine`, and use their combined version inside a `combineLatest` with other `observables`.

I'm not sure how to `combine` them correctly for my Use Case.

First of all let's call them `ObsA` and `ObsB`, and their combined version `ObsCombined`.

```
this.api.ObsA(), 
this.api.ObsB(), 
this.api.ObsCombined()
```

I need that their combined version only `EMITS` values following these rules:

- `ObsB` is a `BehaviourSubject` and its starting value is `Null`.
- when `ObsA` emits, always make `ObsCombined` emit
- if `ObsA` emits "`null`" as next value, then `ObsB` value must be reset (I will call `observable.next(null)`), and `ObsCombined` should then emit both `null` values

So basically, `ObsA` is the most important, and the special thing is, when it emits `Null`, I want to make the other `Obs` reset and emit `Null` as well.

If `ObsB` emits a value, and `ObsA` last emitted was not `Null`, then emit this new value and the previous one from `ObsA`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine 2 observable inside a CombineLatest in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301502/how-to-combine-2-observable-inside-a-combinelatest-in-angular-8)

Comment: no that was my previous question which I worded badly and then reposted here, now the old one is deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **RxJs forkJoin**

```
const obA = this.api.ObsA();
const obB = this.api.ObsB();

forkJoin([obA, obB]).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res[0]);
  console.log(res[1]);
});
```

Comment: but this is missing all the rules I cited above, I don't want the combinedObs to always fire, only if the conditions are respected

Comment: then create nested subscription, and if statement

Answer (score 0):

maybe (not checked)

```
merge(
 obsA.pipe(tap((v)=>{if(v==null) b.next(null)}),
 obsB
).subscribe();
```

Comment: could you give me more info about this code? Not sure I understand it all